# I can't upload my app to the appstore from xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm new to IOS developing and this is my new first app ready to be submitted, however the `Archive` is disabled, and everything is ready in the iTunes connect and the xcode!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have selected "IOS Device" selected not ios simulator to see "Archive" option.or restart system.

Comment: one question please for the idfa i choosed no after that apple said that my app is using because i included admob and iad so i choose yes and i selected that my app only server ads is that ok?

Comment: You need to select "YES" and choose first and last option from idfa section select server advertisement and limit add setting.

Comment: but i sent it and i choose only the first option :(